# Setting up gitlab basic auth htpasswd

Tags: nginx, gitlab, .htpasswd

I am trying to have nginx authentication to a gitlab server.
I have made the changes outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022977/using-gitlab-behind-nginx-enabled-basic-auth).

But I am not sure where to actually generate the htpasswd at.

I've tried these locations;

```
/nginx/.htpasswd
/var/log/gitlab/nginx/.htpasswd
```

Where do I need to put the file? are there any extra configuration steps within gitlab that I cannot find?

Thank you

Comment: I've edited it in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to  give it the location of the htpasswd file, but its still 403 when i generate a password and put in my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. gitlab is looking in the     /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/ directory for htpasswd